# Problems in rendering multiline Time series graph in D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to create a time series graph based on https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1642874
I have multiple lines that gets updated at the same time. Hence, i tried to add them in a group, which is not there in the earlier example.

Here is my complete code.

http://jsfiddle.net/74orxmdg/

However,
I am seeing the following issues

1. Though I have added clippath to remove the lines outside boundary, it is not working. It can be seen that shifted data is getting extended outside the y axis(once it is full).

   ```
       svg.append("defs")
           .append("clipPath").attr("id", "clip").append("rect")
           .attr("width", width)
           .attr("height", height);
   ```
2. It can be seen that graph is first shifted to left and then the new value appears. There is a gap between instant 9 and instant 10 of x2.  But in the code,  I tried to push the value first and then transition is called. I don't understand

   ```
       // Add new values
       for (var name in groups) {
           var group = groups[name]

           group.data.push(Math.random() )
           group.path.attr('d', line)
       }
    paths.attr('transform', null)
           .transition()
           .duration(1000)
           .delay(1000)
           .ease('linear')
           .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(-1) + ',0)')
           .each('end', tick)

       for (var name in groups) {
           var group = groups[name]
           group.data.shift()
       }
   ```
3. If I need to have 1 extra time series graph in the same webpage but with different metrics, What should I do?. The problem is that the Tick function is recursive.

Thanks

Comment: You should probably ask your questions in different, uh, questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate multi-part questions.

For your first issue:  You are transitioning the group which is the clip path.  So the whole thing slides to the left past the y axis boundary. You can fix it by adding another group (containing the lines) apart from the clip path.

```
var paths = svg.append('g')
 .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
 .append('g')
 .attr("class", "line");
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74orxmdg/1/).